# Why to build api

Tags: api

While I'm building rest APIs to build a mobile app, like for example getting product by its sku and find its stock status. I see that APIs are already build by Magento. So why I need to build it? Can anyone give me a strong example, please?

Comment: Magento is already providing these list of APIs https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html you need to just use it.

Comment: There are some APIs which is not available n Magento Only those APIs you need to develop it.